# VBA Excel Convert 3 Columns into an Arrary

Tags: vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I have been searching for a way to do this and I feel like I'm hitting a wall. . . I'm new at VBA, so I may not be going about this the right way.

I have a table that looks like this:

[image: Data]

I need it to look like this:

[image: Result]

The client needs to use this data for various purposes. They tried a Pivot Table, but they hated how it looked and their end users didn't like it either. They also do a lot of other tweaks to the data after it's in the final format.

I was able to get the Names and the Questions to copy/paste to a new sheet in the correct layout. I was then trying to do a For Each loop to filter the Name and copy/paste/transpose the answers to this new sheet. I went this method because the number of questions and names vary all the time.

I do not understand the code I've been seeing and I'm unsure how the older examples I've found online can be manipulated to match my case.

Any suggestions? Or is there another post that is doing something pretty close to what I'm trying to do that I've missed?

Thank you!!

Comment: While I'm sure that your sample data has been simplified, do you know in advance how many questions there are? What about how many names (unique) there are?

Comment: The problem that you've described belongs to a general "crosstab" category, and Pivot Table is a right tool for a job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming that the names are sorted and every name does have the same questions, you could run a simple "double match -1" to get the answer as a worksheet formula. (Having list 1 in sheet1 and list 2 in sheet2)

```
=INDEX(sheet1!$C:$C,MATCH(B$1,INDEX(sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH($A2,sheet1!$A:$A,0)):sheet1!$B$99999,0)+MATCH($A2,sheet1!$A:$A,0)-1)
```

Formula for B2. Fill right and down.

If you don't want the formulas, hide the sheet and copy/paste values only via VBA to another sheet.

[image]

Names do not need to be in complete order but being together "aabb" and "bbaa" will work but "abab" or "baab" will not. Questions do not need to be in any order, but having no "q1" for someone will give him the next "q1" which is found by another name.

Comment: Hi Dirk! Thank you for the help! I am getting a #VALUE! error, though, and I do not know why. . .  I have the original column data on sheet 1 and the "pretty" matrix on sheet 2. What is the :sheet1!B99999 and the +match doing in the formula? Maybe I can figure it out from there.

Comment: Index returns a reference and that said you can do something like `A1:INDEX(A:A,5)` to get the range `A1:A5`. this is used to start the search at the right name. so we rund an `INDEX(range,MATCH())` to get the first row with the right name. Let's say we do search for "b" so we get 6. The match for the question needs to start there but to get an end (so we have a range to look at) we add one. In this case `:sheet1!$B$99999,0)`. now the range to look at is `:sheet1!$6:$B$99999`. (I will update my pictures with an english windows client... just some minutes)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply with `Power Pivot` (a free MS add-in in 2010-2013 (aka `Data --> Get & Transform` in 2016)

Merely

- select the `Questions` Column to Pivot (create new columns)
- Values column --> `Answers`

  - Advanced Options  `Do not aggregate`

[image]

This is the result using your data as posted:

[image]

The only formatting change I made was to turn off the Filter Button under Table Options.

Comment: Hi Ron! This method would be perfect for what I am needing to do. I am not finding the "Do not aggregate" option though. When I create the pivot table in the Power Pivot it looks just like what my clients were originally seeing. It's counting the number of yes/no answers instead of saying "yes" or saying "no".

Comment: @ZAbrami Did you click on `Advanced Options` in the Pivot Column Dialog?  I added a screenshot.

Comment: Aha! I got it! This is perfect!!! Thank you so much!